# MYSQL Query to change all Collation

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have one table that all Collation is set to latin1_swedish_c, i need to change them all to utf8_unicode_ci and set all newone

Is there SQL statment for that, because i have tried

```
ALTER DATABASE  'empinity' convert TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
ALTER TABLE `your table` CHANGE `table_field` `table_field` VARCHAR( 255 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
```

For database:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

For changing collation of all tables as once, run the query:

```
SELECT CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ", TABLE_NAME," COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci") 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="your_database_name"
AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE"
```

Comment: I need for all database

Comment: I need for all tables inside one database